# Export vector graphics from OntoGraf plugin in Protege

Tags: semantic-web, owl, protege, protege4

Is there any way to export Scalable Vector Graphics (SVG) from OntoGraf plugin in Protege? Or is there a similar plugin, from which SVG can be exported?

Answer (score 2):

This can be achieved the following way:

- Inside Protege and in the OntoGraph tab, click the button *Export Graph to DOT* (before last icon). Save it as `onto.dot` somewhere on your machine.
- Then open a terminal and convert the `.dot` file into SVG: `dot -Tsvg onto.dot > output.svg`

The file `output.svg` is the SVG version of your graph.

Comment: Thank you for your reply, but the output.svg contains other graphics
than the OntoGraf plugin in Protege.

Output.svg graphics is like this:
[link](http://www.w3.org/2001/12/rubyrdf/examples/gudge/gudge1.png).
Protege graphics is like this:
[link](http://www.aa3sd.net/IPNI2/images/e/ef/Ontology_example_2.jpg).

Is there a way to export the same graphics as the graphics in OntoGraf plugin? (SVG or any other vector graphic format)

Comment: You can look in the `.dot` file you generate to try to see what's wrong. I don't think it's possible to export directly the picture as in Protege (ask the authors or look the code to see how they do it), but you can style the `.dot` graph. More info at http://www.graphviz.org/Documentation.php about that.

Comment: just to add to @loopasam, you might want to check http://www.graphviz.org/ . once you open the dot file with graphviz, then you export to a wide range of formats, svg included